# Как активировать JS код с помощью requests?

Tags: python, requests

Всех приветствую!

Недавно, мне понадобилось нажать на кнопку в Python с помщью requests (без браузеров наподобее Selenium). Я понимал, что это сделать просто так невозможно. Поэтому, я решил попробовать активировать скрипт кнопки напрямую. Вот скрипт:

```
<script>window.addEventListener('load', function() {$( document ).on( 'submit', '#voteForm', function(e) {e.preventDefault();$.post('/vote/107816/', {"_token": "gZbzAfflTMVN7oIZebwIPOEoGXpoKzZmIBe3bVeN",'g-recaptcha-response': grecaptcha.getResponse()}, function(data){if(data.success) {$("#msgBox").html(data.msg);} else {alert('Unknown error')}});return false;});})</script>
```

Как активировать этот скрипт с помощью requests?

P. S. Не обращайте внимания на капчу, будем считать, что она прошлась *магическим* образом (с помощью CapchaGuru).

Comment: селениум вам в помощь

Comment: @СергейШашко , ну я же сказал, что надо без selenium...

Comment: requests не умеет JS. Зато умеет POST и GET запросы. Общаться с сервером как браузер.

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда какой в данном случае нужен запрос?

Comment: F12 в любом браузере, вкладка "сеть" - там узнаете какой нужен запрос.

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в JS. Что понял я скорее всего посылается POST запрос на адрес '/vote/107816/' с данными {"_token": "gZbzAfflTMVN7oIZebwIPOEoGXpoKzZmIBe3bVeN",'g-recaptcha-response': grecaptcha.getResponse()}. И взависимости от ответа выполняются определенные действия

Comment: Во вкладке "Сеть" я обнаружил следующую картину: Отправляется запрос POST на домен "mysite.ru" с файлом "/vote/107816". То есть надо отправлять этот пакет на "https://mysite.ru/vote/107816"?